# SSH bash script to test if java process is running?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to create a SSH BASH script (on Debian linux) to test if 'java' process is running.

Here how it should look like:

```
IF 'java' process is not running  THEN run ./start.sh
```

to test if java process is running, I can make this test:

```
ps -A | grep java
```

This script should run every minute (I guess in a CRON)

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to run a job every minute in cron, your crontab should look like this:

`* * * * * /path/to/script.sh`

Next, you have a few different options for detecting a Java process.

Note that each of the following is a **negation**: they detect the **absence** of Java:

- With `pgrep`:

  ```
  if [ ! $(pgrep java) ] ; then
    # no java running
  fi
  ```
- With `pidof`:

  ```
  if [ ! $(pidof java) ] ; then
    # no java running
  fi
  ```
- With `ps` and `grep`:

  ```
  if [ ! $(ps -A | grep 'java') ] ; then
    # no java running
  fi
  ```

Of these, `pgrep` and `pidof`are probably the most efficient. Don't quote me on that, though.

Answer (score 1):

The check you are doing with PS and GREP doesn't look very detailed. What if other Java processes are running ? You may detect those, and come to a wrong conclusion, because you are just checking "any" Java, not some specific Java.

Answer (score 0):

With `pidof` would be something like this:

**script.sh**

```
pidof java;
if[$? -ne 0];
then
   # here put your code when errorcode of `pidof` wasn't 0, means that it didn't find process
   # for example: /home/user/start.sh 
   # (please don't forget to use full paths if you want to use it in cron)
fi
```

Especially for haters:

`man pidof`:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> ```
>    0      At least one program was found with the requested name.
>    1      No program was found with the requested name.
> ```